# compileDebugJava - is not incremental. Unable to infer the source directories

Tags: android, gradle, incremental-build

Since Gradle 2.1, incremental compilation of Java source is now supported [check this](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#sec:incremental_compile)

I used below snip of code to enable it

```
afterEvaluate {

    android.applicationVariants.each { variant ->
        variant.javaCompile.options.incremental = true
    }
}
```

But I am getting below warning message,

> :App:compileDebugJava - is not incremental. Unable to infer the source
>   directories.

Please suggest me what should I do to get rid of it

Comment: it is possible that you are trying to compile with java 8 and         sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8. I had amazing problem with this bug and I figured out that you should rather stick with 1_7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Yes, there is an issue for Android Build Plugin, read here:

> We use custom sourceset so this is unlikely to be fixed until we can
>   stop using them.

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=82411 and mentioned here

https://discuss.gradle.org/t/faster-incremental-builds/552/10

### When it is fixed, use this for `Android`, add this in `allProjects`:

```
allProjects {
    tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
        configure(options) {
            incremental = true
        }
    }
}
```

If you see this, you must build your project first:

> compileDebugJava - is not incremental (e.g. outputs have changed, no
>   previous execution, etc.).

If you see this, the wrong `sourceSets` are being used according to the isse(see link):

> compileDebugJava - is not incremental. Unable to infer the source directories.

### From their example for `Java` projects:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
compileJava {
    //enable compilation in a separate daemon process
    options.fork = true

    //enable incremental compilation
    options.incremental = true
}
```

**Source:** http://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile.html

Comment: Using `allProjects` means that you are applying the `incremental` to all of your projects. Currently, `incremental` builds do not seem to be support in `Android`.

Comment: @AmitYadav I know. Please read the links I have provided for you. That is the problem with the Android plugin as I have explained above.

Answer (score 0):

I had such issue with react-native addon packages that I have used. I ran `react-native link` and it seems to have solved the issue.