# Debugging gradle task compileReleaseJavaWithJavac

Tags: android, debugging, gradle, build, travis-ci

I'm writing a custom gradle plugin which generated code and injects some new gradle tasks. My problem is currently that on `gradlew check` the task `compileReleaseJavaWithJavac` or `compileDebugJavaWithJavac` fails.

On windows the task runs fine, on Linux and on mac the task fails. This might be a hint that there is a error with the path or directory separator.

Here is the exact error:

```
:examples:app:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac - is not incremental (e.g. outputs have changed, no previous execution, etc.).
/the/full/path/to/file/MainActivity.java:10: error: package R does not exist
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                        ^
1 error
```

My question is now how can I debug that special task? I would like to see the class path since I guess there goes something wrong.

Before you say but *hey the R file is not generated*: It is. I see the file in the file system.

I was playing a little more when I disable parallel task on a mac it compiles fine too. However on travis it still fails.

Comment: Please, add your travis.yml content to the question or a link to the file.

Comment: @ardock here it is: https://github.com/rekire/PojoBooster/blob/d6b51c81191ecb99017585a28764bb7793da3afe/.travis.yml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated response:**

Currently i only know that:

- It's not a Travis-ci issue because I reproduced it locally on a linux 
  machine.
- It's not related to R package, it's the default package and the import is unnecessary.
- It's not related to the appcompat error, build is successful with any random change.
- Seems something related to incremental builds, [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29731816/1009132), also [this](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/design-docs/incremental-java-compilation.md#open-issues) and  try to set it to false.

> Story: Don't compile a source file when the API of its compile
>   dependencies has not changed
>
> Currently, changing the body of a method invalidates all class files
>   that have been compiled against the method's class. Instead, only the
>   method's class should be recompiled. Similarly, changing a resource
>   file invalidates all class files that included that resource file in
>   the compile classpath. Instead, resource files should be ignored when
>   compiling.
>
> We don't necessarily need a full incremental Java compilation to
>   improve this. For example, the Java compilation task may consider the
>   API of the compile classpath - if it has changed, then compile all
>   source files, and if it has not, skip the task (assuming everything
>   else is up to date). This means that a change to a method body does
>   not propagate through the dependency graph.

Stracktrace error on first build (second build successful):

```
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':examples:app:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
...
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.JdkJavaCompiler.execute(JdkJavaCompiler.java:48)
```

Perhaps [this warning](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16679733/1009132), [Java8](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/cant-build-java-1-8-even-with-proper-java-version-in-use/2461) or [annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21176265/1009132) are related. I hope this helped, I leave because any change I do, makes the build successful and it's hard to understand the real issue.

I configured Java 8 usage like [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/platform/j8-jack.html#configure-gradle):

```
android {
  ...
  defaultConfig {
    ...
    jackOptions {
      enabled true
    }
  }
  compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
  }
}
```

**Previous response:**

Try to add to your `MainActivity.java` the next import using your real package:

```
import your.package.R;
```

R file is not correctly generated due to previous errors like this:

```
COMPILE-Error: package android.support.v7.app does not exist
```

I just tested it. I downloaded your project on a linux machine (it's not a travis-ci issue).

I replaced the dependency by the next line and it works:

```
compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0"
```

So I suggest you to add `{ }`:

```
compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${project.supportLibVersion}"
```

Really, I'm not sure, now it's working always without the suggested changes.

Perhaps, it's true that it's about parallel option issue and worked on second run, but we are close.